# Do I need to make .sh file executable on Windows?

Tags: python, bash

I want to make a bash file `run.sh` such that users can execute it on their systems. However, I am using Windows and am unsure if there is a similar way to make a file executable.

How I would do it on a Linux system with directory as follows:

```sh
src
├── train.py            - training/optimization pipelines
└── utils.py            - utility functions
requirements.txt
run.sh
README.md
```

Then I create `run.sh` file with `chmod +x run.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 src/main.py
```

I got two questions:

1. In Windows, do I need to type anything to make the `run.sh` file executable?
2. Am I calling my `python3 src/main.py` path correctly in the `sh` file? Will this work for all systems?

Comment: Open it as a Text File and save it as 'run.bat'. That's simple on Windows. Don't forget to select the (*All files) option as the file format.

Comment: If the concern is the executable bit, you can run `git update-index --chm
od=+x run.sh` after adding it to make it executable on platforms that support that concept.

Comment: What bash implementation do you have installed? Basically, you can register on Windows an association between a certain exe-file with a certain file extension, with the effect that this file is by default executed with an exe file. I could imagine that this strategy would work with i.e. git-bash or Cygwin bash, but I never tried it. This question, however, is not about programming and should be asked on i.e. [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not have Bash and cannot run `.sh` files natively, unless you have Bash / compatible shell installed in some way, e.g. the Windows Subsystem for Lunix (WSL). If you have that, it is Linux so chmod is the same, but it will only work from within that environment.

Otherwise you will need a Windows script, e.g. a batch file. You could put these same lines in, and save as `run.bat` and it would be executable in Windows:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 src/main.py
```

(As long as `pip` and `python3` are in a folder in the PATH environment variable).

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, I have no issues running the `.sh` file on windows since I do have `git bash` or WSL. But I am unsure if other people who clone my repo can run the `.sh` file if I did not make it executable using `chmod` command. The confusion lies in me not running `chmod` and my lack of understanding on whether it is needed if i created the file on Windows.

Comment: @ilovewt Ah; on Linux the `+x` bit is part of the filesystem permissions, read write execute. Windows/NTFS does not have that, and uses file extension for executables (`.bat`, `.com`, `.exe`, etc.). Git Bash is MinGW [which seems to have deliberately no kind of support](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1475/) for pretending `chmod +x` can do anything useful on Windows; maybe Git could add something, but it seems to me that `.sh` files are executable in that environment without doing anything extra to them.